# How to force minted to hide any overflow?

Tags: pdftex, minted, overflow

`minted` package in LaTeX has a possibility to automatically wrap lines. But how to let the lines as they are and force the `minted` package to hide any possible overflow? This might be useful for a database example like this:

```
Output:

\begin{minted}{text}
id     | title                                                                                                                            | date | date_acquired | classification_id
-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------+------------------
5569   | Zeichnet 5 1/2 Dritte Kriegs-Anleihe                                                                                             | 1916 | 1968-03-07    | 7                
6214   | In the Forward Capitalist Countries the Share of Exploiting Classes in the National Income Consists of Approximately 50 or More  | 1930 | 1943-05-12    | 7                
109440 | 60 Off, New York                                                                                                                 | 2007 | 2007-05-10    | 9                
183530 | Warhead I (Regan 55, Brezhnev 45, Thatcher less than 1, Mitterrand less than 1, Deng less than 1)                                | 1982 | 2014-10-09    | 9                
193145 | MyDesktop                                                                                                                        | 2002 | 2015-05-21    | 12               
284019 | Jacket Cover for Upton Sinclair's 100%           
\end{minted}
```

[image]

As you see in the above picture, the overflow is visible which is not desirable. Might this be done by some hidden option of the minted package? Or at least by any other means?

Comment: An answer to this question would be highly anticipated still. :-)